# C# RabbitMQ why is the second worker not picking up work?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am trying to understand all the RabbitMQ options what I think I want its just a worker queue so I have one queue and workers just take off one item and process it.

I create a new Direct Exchange (I think that is right!?)

Firstly I would like to know why in this example, I add 4 new messages to the exchange/queue. I don't start any workers. I then start the first worked and then the second, but the second one does not process any and the first worked processes them all!?

[image]

What am I doing wrong, why does this not work? please find the full example code below.

I also don't seem to have the publish confirms working right, as only sometimes on the right most output does it say "Message Acknowledged..."
I have read https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html and gone through the other pages that follow, but it's not hugely clear.

The emitter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using RabbitMQ.Client;

namespace PublishConfirms.Emit
{
    class Program
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, string> _outstandingConfirms = new ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, string>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = "localhost"
            };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    // We need to enable published confirms on the channel
                    channel.ConfirmSelect();

                    channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "DirectExchange",
                        type: ExchangeType.Direct);

                    var queueName = "DirectExchangeQueue";
                    // Make sure to create the queue in case it doesn't exits
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                        durable: true,
                        exclusive: false,
                        autoDelete: false,
                        arguments: null);

                    channel.BasicAcks += (sender, ea) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Message Acknowledged with Delivery Tag {0}", ea.DeliveryTag);
                        // message is confirmed
                        CleanOutstandingConfirms(ea.DeliveryTag, ea.Multiple);
                    };

                    channel.BasicNacks += (sender, ea) =>
                    {
                        // message is nack-ed (messages that have been lost
                        _outstandingConfirms.TryGetValue(ea.DeliveryTag, out string body);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Message with body {body} has been nack-ed. Sequence number: {ea.DeliveryTag}, multiple: {ea.Multiple}");
                        CleanOutstandingConfirms(ea.DeliveryTag, ea.Multiple);
                    };

                    var message = "A message here";
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                    _outstandingConfirms.TryAdd(channel.NextPublishSeqNo, message);

                    var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                    properties.Persistent = true;

                    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                        routingKey: queueName,
                        basicProperties: properties,
                        body: body);

                    Console.WriteLine("Sent message '{0}'", message);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void CleanOutstandingConfirms(ulong sequenceNumber, bool multiple)
        {
            if (multiple)
            {
                var confirmed = _outstandingConfirms.Where(k => k.Key <= sequenceNumber);
                foreach (var entry in confirmed)
                {
                    _outstandingConfirms.TryRemove(entry.Key, out _);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _outstandingConfirms.TryRemove(sequenceNumber, out _);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The worker/receiver

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

namespace PublishConfirms.Receive
{
    class Program
    {
        // We can run multiples of these and only one will get a messages from the queue with no sharing
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = "localhost"
            };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    // This will create the exchange if needed
                    channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "DirectExchange",
                        type: ExchangeType.Direct);

                    var queueName = "DirectExchangeQueue";
                    // Make sure to create the queue in case it doesn't exits
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                        durable: true,
                        exclusive: false,
                        autoDelete: false,
                        arguments: null);

                    channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                        exchange: "DirectExchange",
                        routingKey: ""); // We keep the routing key the same as we dont want different handlers
                    // If we were to have different routes then we 
                    // would most probably have to create a random queue e.g.
                    // var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for messages...");

                    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                    {
                        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                        Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Processing...");
                        Thread.Sleep(3000); // simulate some work
                        Console.WriteLine("Processing Complete");
                        // send an acknowledgement back
                        channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
                    };

                    channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                        autoAck: false,
                        consumer: consumer);

                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading what itama said I had another look and firstly the BasicPublish exchange was an empty string so that would have not helped! I decided against using the routing key as the queue name and kept it as an empty string.

For me I wanted an exchange with a single queue and then multiple workers that would handle one item from the queue at a time.

The issue with it only being handled by one worked seemed to be resolved when I added in this piece of code on the worker.

```
channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
```

After adding this the other workers got a message each. I ended up adding 50-100 messages to the queue and then started 10 workers, they all got a queue item and processed it which was nice to see.

For the Publish Confirm BasicAcks and BasicNacks callbacks I found this link https://rianjs.net/2013/12/publisher-confirms-with-rabbitmq-and-c-sharp this states that we need to call the **channel.WaitFormConfirmsOrDie()** after making the **BasicPublish** call, previously my code was not waiting for an acknowledgement.

The full code is as follows:

The emitter/producer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using RabbitMQ.Client;

namespace PublishConfirms.Emit
{
    class Program
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, string> _outstandingConfirms = new ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, string>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = "localhost"
            };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    

                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // Setup the Exchange and Queue then bind the queue to the exchange
                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    
                    // This will create the exchange if needed
                    channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "DirectExchange",
                        type: ExchangeType.Direct);

                    var queueName = "DirectExchangeQueue";
                    // Make sure to create the queue in case it doesn't exits
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                        durable: true,
                        exclusive: false,
                        autoDelete: false,
                        arguments: null);

                    channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                        exchange: "DirectExchange",
                        routingKey: "");

                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // Setup Publish Confirms
                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    channel.BasicAcks += (sender, ea) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Message Acknowledged with Delivery Tag {0}", ea.DeliveryTag);
                        // message is confirmed
                        CleanOutstandingConfirms(ea.DeliveryTag, ea.Multiple);
                    };

                    channel.BasicNacks += (sender, ea) =>
                    {
                        // message is nack-ed (messages that have been lost)
                        _outstandingConfirms.TryGetValue(ea.DeliveryTag, out string body);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Message with body {body} has been nack-ed. Sequence number: {ea.DeliveryTag}, multiple: {ea.Multiple}");
                        CleanOutstandingConfirms(ea.DeliveryTag, ea.Multiple);
                    };

                    // We need to enable published confirms on the channel
                    channel.ConfirmSelect();

                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // Setup The message and add it to the ConcurrentDictionary, so we can 
                    // Remove it when the BasicAcks is called
                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    var message = "YOUR MESSAGE HERE";
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                    var nextPublishSequenceNo = channel.NextPublishSeqNo;
                    Console.WriteLine("Next Publish Sequenece Number: {0}", nextPublishSequenceNo);
                    _outstandingConfirms.TryAdd(nextPublishSequenceNo, message);

                    // Make sure the message is written to disk as soon as it reaches the queue
                    // Imagine this will be slower but safer, this is also stored in memory if there is no memory pressure!
                    var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                    properties.Persistent = true;

                    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "DirectExchange",
                        routingKey: "",
                        basicProperties: properties,
                        body: body);
                    channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie();
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent message '{0}'", message);
                }
            }
        }

        static void CleanOutstandingConfirms(ulong sequenceNumber, bool multiple)
        {
            if (multiple)
            {
                var confirmed = _outstandingConfirms.Where(k => k.Key <= sequenceNumber);
                foreach (var entry in confirmed)
                {
                    _outstandingConfirms.TryRemove(entry.Key, out _);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _outstandingConfirms.TryRemove(sequenceNumber, out _);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The receiver/worker:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

namespace PublishConfirms.Receive
{
    class Program
    {
        // We can run multiples of these and only one will get a messages from the queue with no sharing
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = "localhost"
            };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // Setup the Exchange and Queue then bind the queue to the exchange
                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                    
                    // This will create the exchange if needed
                    channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "DirectExchange",
                        type: ExchangeType.Direct);

                    var queueName = "DirectExchangeQueue";
                    // Make sure to create the queue in case it doesn't exits
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                        durable: true,
                        exclusive: false,
                        autoDelete: false,
                        arguments: null);

                    // Only dispatch one message at a time to a worked and wait for its acknowledgement
                    // Adding this in seems to correct the issue where only one worker would pick
                    // up the queued items
                    channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

                    // We keep the routing key the same as we don't want different handlers
                    // If we were to have different routes then we 
                    // would most probably have to create a random queue e.g.
                    // var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
                    channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                        exchange: "DirectExchange",
                        routingKey: ""); 

                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for messages...");

                    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                    {
                        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                        Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Processing...");
                        Thread.Sleep(3000); // simulate some work
                        Console.WriteLine("Processing Complete");
                        // send an acknowledgement back
                        channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
                    };

                    channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                        autoAck: false,
                        consumer: consumer);

                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lays in understanding how the `Direct` exchange works, and probably the queue `binding keys` and `routing keys` as well.
A `Direct` exchange deliveries its messages to the queues whose `binding key` exactly matches the `routing key` of the message.
The `binding key` is the key the queue is binding to the exchange by.
The `routing key` is the key the message sent is routed by

Therefore the problem with your code is either:

- With publishing your messages:

```cs
...

 channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                        routingKey: "", // 
                        basicProperties: properties,
                        body: body);

...
```

- Or you could change the binding key when creating the queue:

```cs
...

 channel.QueueBind(queue: queueName,
                        exchange: "DirectExchange",
                        routingKey: queueName); // As you stated in your code that 
                                                // the queue name is your bindingKey

...
```

You can choose whichever one you prefer.

---

Other than that, when you publish your message you do it to an empty exchange name,
it should be:

```cs
channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "DirectExchange", // As you stated at the start of your code
                        routingKey: queueName,
                        basicProperties: properties,
                        body: body);
```

---

I'd suggest reading up more about [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) and understanding more of the concepts about their implementation.
You may want to see references about:

- [Fanout Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-fanout)
- [Routing](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html)

I hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks I'll follow what you said and see what happens